# Find a recurrence relation for the length-$n$ LED strip

Tags: combinatorics

You wish to program an LED strip containing $n$ LEDs. Each individual LED can be lit in red, green, blue, or white. How many length-$n$ colour sequences have at least one pair of adjacent LEDs that light up with the same colour? Hint: Find a recurrence relation. Also order matters (eg: GGR and RGG are different).

I'm thinking use $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2^{n-2}?$$ but not sure about the intial condition and how to get rid of the possibilities has been counted before. like for considering red with n=4:there's RRGG and consider green with n=4: there's RRGG are the same.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The complementary number (i.e. the number of strips with **no** consecutive same-colour lights) is easily calculable: after choosing the first light from $4$ choices the remainder have $3$ choices, the excluded colour being that which was most recently chosen. Thus the final answer is $4^n-4\cdot3^{n-1}$.